# adding background images one after another horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 3 different background images and I want to add them one after another one horizontally.

```
#bgwrap{width:100%;height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
#bg1{width:1000px;height:100%; background: #000 url(bg1.jpg) no-repeat center top;}
#bg2{width:1000px;height:100%; background: #000 url(bg2.jpg) no-repeat center top;}
#bg3{width:1000px;height:100%; background: #000 url(bg3.jpg) no-repeat center top;}
```

later I can use jquery to pick only view start width=1001px to 2000px when I want to see the second background.
So how do I add them together into a single class or ID, so I can use jquery to select it?

Comment: When you say add them one after another horizontally, do you mean upon the page loading, or as someone scrolls to the left (or right) and brings them into view?

Comment: Keep those image url paths in an array. and then use jquery to pick the image path from the array.

Comment: yea, the reason i want to add them horizontally is because I want to scroll them left or right

Answer (score 2):

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8AaJz/3/)

You can set a default background, and then change it with jQuery.

```
$('body').css({
    'background-image': 'url('+ newBackgroundImage + ')'
});
```

---

In my demo I stored them in an array.

```
var bgs = ['bg1.jpg', 'bg2.jpg', '...'];
```

If you need to preload each of them, you can create Images.

```
var ct = 0;
function loaded(){
    ct++;
    if (ct === bgs.length) {
        // all images are loaded
    }
}

for (var i=0; i<bgs.length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.onload = loaded;
    img.src = bgs[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4tb6Q/

```
<div id="div1">img1</div>
<div id="div2">img2</div>
<div id="div3">img3</div>
```

css

```
div {
height: 60px; //image height
width:60px; //image width
position:absolute;
}
```

jquery

```
$("button").click(function(){    
var $divL=$("div:last");
var $divF=$("div:first");
$divL.remove().insertBefore($divF);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#main_div{ width:1000px;overflow:hidden;}
#pic_div{width:3000px}
#pic1{width:1000px;float:left;background: #000 url(bg1.jpg)}
#pic2{width:1000px;float:left;background: #000 url(bg2.jpg)}
#pic3{width:1000px;background: #000 url(bg3.jpg)}
<div id="main_div">
  <div id="pic_div">
  <div id="pic1"></div>
  <div id="pic2"></div>
  <div id="pic3"></div>
  </div>
</div>

$("#main_div").click(function(){
if($("#pic_div").css("margin-left")<2000)
 {
var a=$("#pic_div").css("margin-left");
a=a+1000;
a=a+"px";
$("#pic_div").css("margin-left",a);
  }
else
 {
$("#pic_div").css("margin-left",'0px');
 }

});
```

Comment: where do I put my other content? if I add a new content div outside main_div, all my content get push down.